# Intune - Using custom attributes with macOS devices in for Compliance Policies and Conditional access

Tags: macos, office365, intune

I am trying to figure out if this is a use case in InTune, but have not found a way to do so. I have a set of attributes that I am pulling as custom attributes from macOS devices which I would like to use for a compliance policy to tie in with conditional access.

Does anyone know of a way to do this? I cannot seem to find a path to make this work.